# Intersection of a line with a curve given as a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
  \large y = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x+1}{2x-1}\right)^k
$$

I need to calculate the point at which this curve intersects with the line $3y=x-1$.

I understand that I need to substitute the curve and line to form one equation, but am unsure of how to do so because the sum of y is infinite.

Comment: The sum is a geometric series - do you know how to sum this?

Comment: Well I know the general formula for geometric series but for that I need to know how many terms I am summing.. so I don't know how to work with infinite terms.

Comment: If $r = \frac{x+1}{2x-1}$ has modulus less than 1 the sum has a limit $\frac{1}{1-r}$. You will end up with something like a quadratic for x when you substitute for y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum is a geometric series of the kind
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k$$
For the sum to be convergent, $|r|$ must be lesser than $1$. If the sum converges, its limit is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}$$.

For the inequality $|\frac{x+1}{2x-1}|\lt 1$ to be verified, $x$ must be in the interval $(-\infty,0)\cup(2,+\infty)$

Under this constraint, the system of equations is readily solved through a substitution of $r$ and $y=\frac{x-1}{3}$

$$y-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{x+1}{2x-1})^k=\frac{x-1}{3}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{x+1}{2x-1}}=\cdots$$

Can you take it from here?